# Can we write $sl(4,\mathbb{C})$ as the vector space sum of two copies of $sl(3,\mathbb{C})$?

Tags: lie-algebras

We know $sl(4,\mathbb{C})$ has dimension $15$ and $sl(3,\mathbb{C})$ has dimension $8$. Is it possible to write $sl(4,\mathbb{C})$ as the vector space sum of two Lie subalgebras that are isomorphic to $sl(3,\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: No. Up to conjugation, a copy of $sl_3$ in $sl_4$ is (the derived subalgebra of) the stabilizer of a $3+1$ decomposition $H\oplus L$. The intersection of any two such stabilizers contains a copy of $sl_2$. Hence the sum has dimension $\le 8+8-3=13$.

Answer (score 2):

A. L. Onishchik has determined such semisimple decompositions (not necessarily direct sums) in his article [Decompositions of reductive Lie groups](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/SM1969v009n04ABEH001292). For example, it is true that for simple Lie algebras
$$
A_{2n-1}=A_{2n-2}+C_n.
$$
For $n=2$ this gives $A_3=A_2+C_2$, i.e., $\mathfrak{sl}(4)=\mathfrak{sl}(3)+\mathfrak{sp}(4)$. However, $A_3=A_2+A_2$ is not possible.